# how to use a different keyStore for the some account?

Tags: android, google-play

I have I have an account on the play store  with an application. But when I tried to upload my new application, I used a different keystore, I want to publish the new application but with the new keystore and not the former, because I have already installed the application on multiple tablets but with the new certification. if I use the old keyStore I would have problems of certifications. So how can I use my new KeyStore with my existing account.

Comment: Just sign your app with new keystore and upload it. whats the issue in this?

Comment: when i use an existing account. i ought to use the some key that i used for my first application.